# inserting file contents in the middle of another file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Suppose I have  3 text files

*file1*

```
this is
some 
text
-------
```

*file2*

```
this is
another
pretty 
text
--------
```

*file3*

```
a
b
%file1%
d
e
x
y
%file2%
...
```

I would like to insert file1 and file2 contents to file3 to substitute their appropriate "markers" . Markers can be in any place within file3.

This is not working for me for some reason.

```
a=`cat file1'
cat file3 | sed "s/%file1%/\"$a\"/"
```

I am geetting following error

```
sed: unrecognized option '--------'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to read all three files and update the markers:-

```
awk '
        FILENAME ~ /file1/ {
                f1 = f1 ? f1 RS $0 : $0
                next
        }
        FILENAME ~ /file2/ {
                f2 = f2 ? f2 RS $0 : $0
                next
        }
        /%file1%/ {
                $0 = f1
        }
        /%file2%/ {
                $0 = f2
        }
        1
' file1 file2 file3
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^%\(.*\)%/cat \1/e' file3
```

This will insert the files named between `%`'s in file3.

Comment: I'm liking the `s///e`.  I think you forgot `-i` though.